# Wrist Yaw Kinect 1.8

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I would like to know on how one could track the angle of the wrist yaw by using a Microsoft Kinect. Right now i am using the following code:

```
Joint wrist = skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft];
Joint hand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
Joint elbow = skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft];
Joint hipCenter = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter];

Vector3D vectorWristHand = new Vector3D(wrist.Position.X - hand.Position.X, wrist.Position.Y - hand.Position.Y, wrist.Position.Z - hand.Position.Z);
Vector3D vectorElbowWrist = new Vector3D(elbow.Position.X - wrist.Position.X, elbow.Position.Y - wrist.Position.Y, elbow.Position.Z - wrist.Position.Z);
Vector3D vectorElbowHip = new Vector3D(elbow.Position.X - hipCenter.Position.X, elbow.Position.Y - hipCenter.Position.Y, elbow.Position.Z - hipCenter.Position.Z);

Vector3D cpCenterWrist = Vector3D.CrossProduct(vectorElbowHip, vectorElbowWrist);
Vector3D cpWrist = Vector3D.CrossProduct(cpCenterWrist, vectorWristHand);

return AngleBetweenTwoVectors(cpCenterWrist, cpWrist, inDegrees);
```

Which was supposed to return me the angle of the wrist yaw. However my mathematic skills are not so good and it's very hard to come up with a decent implementation if i don't have a clear understanding of the maths.

Perhaps someone could also explain me on which exact vectors i could use for this and if it is even possible to track the wrist yaw movement on the Kinect.

Comment: how are you defining 'yaw' for the wrist? It seems to me that you cant know whether the hand is palm up or down from just the location of joints

Comment: Yes that's what i thought. So it might not be possible to track the yaw?

Comment: not in the sense of, 'angle between the thumb side of the hand and the forearm' but you could define it differently. eg you could say its the angle between the horizontal component of the hand direction and the horizonal component of the facing direction

Comment: essentially you have to choose which way is up

Comment: Would you happen to have any examples of this? I'm quite new to kinect programming

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't done any kinect programming. Just answering from a vector maths pov. It looks like you code is fine, you are just calculating an angle that isnt matching your conception of 'wrist yaw'

Comment: I think your cpCenterWrist as UP is fine, but your cpWrist is where you are going wrong. you want just the component of the vector projected onto the horizontal plane as defined by your 'UP'. Should this be a dot product?

Comment: ... you need another vector to define the plane, perhapse the elbow-wrist? so elbow-wrist dot wrist-hand = x cpCenterWrist dot wrist-hand = z gives you pitch and (cpCenterWrist cross elbow-wrist) dot wrist-hand = y gives you yaw

Comment: I used the following `var y = Vector3D.DotProduct(Vector3D.CrossProduct(cpCenterWrist, vectorElbowWrist), vectorWristHand);` but the angles it reports are very small (like 10^-5) which is supposed to be 180 degrees sometimes (or pi rad)